# Read and write from global variables

Tags: java, arrays, global

What I'm trying to do is have a global variable classes and function can read/write from/to.

What I have now is

```
import java.lang.*;             
import lab1.Global;
public class SecondProgram {
     public static void main ( String args[] ) {
            System.out.println("hi ");
            Global.b[0] = " zero ";
            Global.b[1] = " One ";
            Global.b[2] = " Two ";
            Global.b[3] = " Three ";

        }
}
```

and I created a class to store the global variables

```
public class Global {
  public static String a = "hi" ;
  public static String [] b;
}
```

Of course it is important that the size of the array isn't a hardcoded constant but a variable I'll be able to find out at some point and plug in.

I hope you can see from the code what I'm trying to do, and you know how to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you *want* global variables?

Comment: if you are worried about the size of an array, use a list?

Comment: i think you have confused java with some other language, this is not how we do things in java. My opinion is that you should redesign your program. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want global variables because i am having threads read data from text files into arrays, and it's important that the arrays and their data stay present after the thread finishes its work

Comment: Perhaps a better approach than globals, then, is some sort of `ThreadManager` class which has a list of `FileData` objects, one of which is passed to each `Thread` to add its data.  When the threads are done, the `ThreadManager` can walk through the data they collected.

Comment: @cheeken this sounds interesting, but I don't have time to learn how to make a threadmanager class and use it :/, do you think the global variables way would work?

Comment: How do you intend to coordinate communication between your threads?  For example, how will one thread know that another thread is done, and that the data it needs is available?  Fundamentally your problem is one of coordinating communication between threads, and using global variables is definitely not a recommended way to accomplish this.

Comment: @JimN actually i am not trying to have a communication between threads, just threads who'll dump info into a couple of arrays, and then i want to keep those arrays and use them in the main program and other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is a far better approach and something to get you started....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SecondProgram {

    private static ArrayList <String>file = new ArrayList();

    public synchronized boolean  writeFile(String str){
        //wrtite file to your list
        file.add(str);
        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //read file and use the synchronized method to write it to your list
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I want global variables because i am having threads read data from text files into arrays, and it's important that the arrays and their data stay present after the thread finishes its work.

Well that won't work.  Or at least, it won't work *reliably* (and in a sense that is a worse outcome!)

In a multi-threaded Java program, you need to be sure that the threads synchronize properly at points where information gets passed from one to another.  The purpose of the synchronization is twofold:

- to prevent race conditions; i.e. where one thread tries to read a value before another one has read it, and
- to ensure that threads don't see *stale* copies of values due to memory caching effects.

Synchronizing bare global variables is going to be fiendishly hard.  My advice is

- Pay attention to the comments (above) and design and implement using classes to encapsulate the state.
- Use the utility classes in `java.util.concurrent` to implement the shared data structures ... and handle thread creation / management.  Look at the ExecutorService API for example,
- Get a good textbook on concurrent programming in Java.  Concurrency in Java is not simple, and if you don't know what you are doing you can spend hours / days / weeks / months tracking down the causes of intermittent failures.

Answer (score 1):

I don't advocate the use of globals, but if you must, you can do something like the following.  In general: have each thread build up its own data.  When it is finished doing its work, add its data to a synchronized global collection (in this case, a `List<List<String>>`).  Then read that collection once all of the threads have finished their work.

The global that collects the data:

```
public class GlobalDataBroker {
    public static List<List<String>> data = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<List<String>>());
}
```

An example implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
                list.add(String.format("I'm a Thread and my name is %s.",Thread.currentThread()));
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    list.add("Data!");
                }
                GlobalDataBroker.data.add(list);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    // When the threads are done ...            
    Iterator<List<String>> i = GlobalDataBroker.data.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[I'm a Thread and my name is Thread[Thread-8,5,main]., Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!]
[I'm a Thread and my name is Thread[Thread-5,5,main]., Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!]
...
[I'm a Thread and my name is Thread[Thread-7,5,main]., Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!, Data!]
```

Note that you should only begin iterating over your data once you've completed writing it.  (Otherwise, you may encounter the dreaded `ConcurrentModificationException`.)